# Horizontal Align Two Images in a DIV

Tags: html, image, alignment

I have two images that I'm trying to center align horizontally. Currently they look like this...

[image]

But, I would like the "APPLY NOW" button to be horizontally aligned like so...

[image]

My current code for the two images is this...

```
<img class="alignright" src="image1.png" alt="" />
<img src="image2.png" align="right">
```

I've attempted to center align them without CSS, and I'd prefer not to use CSS if there is a way I can do it without it. If I have to use CSS, then I'd appreciate any help that is provided!

Thanks!

Comment: any formatting you do on your page mainly is written in CSS ;-) but why don't you want to use it??

Comment: @SaschaP I'm well aware, CSS is quite useful! Haha. I'm just using HTML editing in Wordpress, and wasn't sure if not using CSS would be any easier. But I'm all for anything that makes this work!

Comment: If you dont want to use css you could always make your apply now image the same height as your doctor image and just align it properly using your image editor.  Just to clarify I am not suggesting stretching the button but just adding whitespace around it within the image.

Comment: @Jrod Thanks for that! I was intending to do that with the whitespace, but I need to make this image into a link, and adding that whitespace will also create the link much larger than the button itself, correct?

Comment: @LoganDeyo It would but if you aren't putting anything in that space I wouldn't worry too much about that. Just a bigger click area for the user.  But if you are using wordpress I would make some sort of template, custom post type, shortcode or something else to implement this giving you more control without having to use the html editor in wordpress.

Comment: @Jrod Thanks for your help. I think I actually figured it out. I used the image, and added margin's from the top so it sat centered horizontally. Basically created whitespace without extending the graphic. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

With CSS just use the `vertical-align` property with the value `middle`

More about vertical-align: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Without css... I've no idea.

Answer (score 0):

add the following css to the parent box or element which the images are in:

```
style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"
```

hth

Answer (score 0):

Just apply two rules to the second image .

```
<img class="alignright" src="image1.png" alt="" />
<img class="center" src="image2.png" align="right">

css code:
.center{
positon:relative;
top:50%;
bottom:50%;
}
```